# Stripe Connect Payout Alternatives

Tags: stripe-payments, payment

In my application I need that customers can pay and also receive money.
For the first part I'm using stripe without any problem. Now I'm searching a way for the second part. I heard about Stripe connect payout but unfortunately it is available in US only.

Stripe connect payout is very close to what I want to achieve: send money to my customers from my application. Is there any alternatives available in Europe? I still don't have any bank account so I'm open to any suggestions (maybe some bank account have some sort of API).

I looked also at Paypal payout but if is possible I don't want to force my customers to use paypal.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: > heard about Stripe connect payout but unfortunately it is available in US only. 
That's definitely not true, you can payout to an account in any of the countries Stripe supports. https://stripe.com/global

Comment: As far as I can read from https://stripe.com/connect/payouts "Connect Payouts is currently only available in the US."

Comment: Payouts are definitely available in many countries. It's possible that in your specific country, there may be an issue, or you may be confusing normal payouts with *Instant Payouts*. Still, I'd recommend contacting [Stripe Support](https://support.stripe.com) as they can give you a definitive answer as far as what you can use Stripe for.

Comment: Are you sure your not confusing payout with connect payout? BTW I'll contact the support.